# Gradle fails to download package from Github Package Registry

Tags: gradle, github-package-registry

Uploading the public package with gradle works:
https://github.com/ttiganik/hrd-java-test-registry/packages/61312

But I am unable to download it. I tried different [URL-s and package names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58398575/accessing-private-maven-github-package-registry-with-gradle), but none of them work.

According to documentation the correct URL-s should be:

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url "https://maven.pkg.github.com/ttiganik/hrd-java-test-registry"
        credentials {
            username = System.properties['hmGithubUser']
            password = System.properties['hmGithubToken']
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.ttiganik:test:1.0.0'
}
```

The credentials are the same as for uploading.

`gradle installDebug` says it looks from the correct location:

```
> Could not find com.ttiganik:test:1.0.0.
  Searched in the following locations:
    - https://maven.pkg.github.com/ttiganik/com/ttiganik/test/1.0.0/test-1.0.0.pom
    - https://maven.pkg.github.com/ttiganik/com/ttiganik/test/1.0.0/test-1.0.0.jar
  Required by:
```

but it doesn't install it.

If I comment out the credentials in maven repository, it says 401 unauthorised. So the location seems to be correct.

What is wrong with my GPR configuration?

Comment: After reading this I suspect you need a READ token on GitHub just to pull the package: https://proandroiddev.com/publishing-android-libraries-to-the-github-package-registry-part-1-7997be54ea5a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I didn't include correct package name. You need to include package name 2x.

```
-     implementation 'com.ttiganik:test:1.0.0'
+     implementation 'com.ttiganik.test:test:1.0.0'
```

It's easier to just copy the dependency straight from Github. They include the correct name

Answer (score 0):

Had this same issue and discovered that if you're part of an organization on Github, you might have to grant/authorise your token to be able to access your organisation for it to be able to work. Go to your personal access token in Account -> Settings -> Developer Settings -> Personal Access Token -> Tokens (classic).

Then click on `Configure SSO` if applicable, then find your organisation and click authorise.